# Calling a Model Function in View?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a function called getThumbnail() in model.

How do I call this function in the view file.

Currently what I have to use is:

```
<?php
$tmp = new Model();
echo $tmp->getThumbnail(1);
?>
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this, because calling to Model directly from View doesn't look right.

Comment: ...there's a quite nice concept for it, called _controller_, the C in MVC. Have a look at it and it's concepts.

Comment: I know about controllers. The problem is, a parameter has to be passed into getThumbnail() function and the parameter is acquired inside a loop in the view.

Comment: What exactly is "model function"? Model is **not** a class or object. Model is a layer. If you want to access structure from it, you should be using services: `$im = $this->serviceFactory->create('ImageProcessing'); $im->getThumbnail($i);`. The `serviceFactory` should be a dependency both for views an controllers. Then again ... I get a feeling that you do not have "views". Only bunch of dumb templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to call to Model from the View.

Views are the minions of the controller. Model should be communicated only from the controller.

Answer (score 2):

How to do this correctly is quite a broad topic, there's no one correct answer. However, one thing I would definitely point out is that instantiating a model class inside the view is definitely wrong. Instead, you should either:

1. pass an instance of `Model` from the controller to the view, or
2. pass a "dispatcher" object from the controller to the view which allows the view to call any or some model functions indirectly, e.g.:

   ```
   echo $dispatcher->dispatch('Model', 'getThumbnail', 1);
   ```

   It makes a lot of sense if the model methods this dispatcher allows are restricted, to enforce decent separation of concerns. For example, the view should never make any calls that modify state in the model, like `User::createNewUser` or some such. The view should only be allowed to call "passive" model methods to get data.

The main point being here that you want to *inject* dependencies into the view, instead of hardcoding specific model calls directly. This pretty much goes for any dependency, not just view-model relations.

Comment: That can be very simple or very complex. The above one could simply be `public function dispatch($class, $method, $arg) { $obj = new $class; return $obj->$method($arg); }` But you probably need more logic for instantiating your class, for which you may want a registry or a dependency injection container. Either way, you should learn more about dependency injection. That should show you why your current code is bad and will more or less automatically lead you in the right direction if you understand and follow the philosophy from start to end.

Comment: @tereško I'm sorry I have displeased you with this answer by not going into the whole philosophical background about MVC and DI and maybe labeling some concepts differently than you did.

Comment: The problem is your disregard of LoD, SRP and what the hell is "dispatcher"?